# Mutex in JNI using Foundation NSLock

Tags: java, cocoa, multithreading, java-native-interface, mutex

I have some objective-c code that uses an NSLock to implement a sort of transaction.  The object is locked on a "begin transaction", several other calls are made with the lock in place, and then it's released with a "commit".  I'm writing a JNI glue layer to access this code from Java, but the lock is behaving differently in JNI vs pure objc code.

I have unit tests in both Java and objc that exercise the code that makes the lock.  The objc test passes, but in the Java test [anNSLock tryLock] returns false even though [anNSLock lock] hasn't been called.

Is there a recommended way to have a mutex in JNI?  I'm not sure what the underlying mechanism for NSLock is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [NSLock](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says that NSLock uses Posix threads.  Does Java use Posix threads?

A couple of alternative: The first is to create a synchronized wrapper in Java for your object.  The second is to use the JNI MonitorEnter and MonitorExit methods for synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I think the page below will be helpful, as it talks about mutexes in addition to MonitorEnter, etc.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html

I think my question was a little unclear (synchronize is probably out as a solution, but monitor enter / exit could work).  I rewrote the first part to read:

'I have some objective-c code that uses an NSLock to implement a sort of transaction.  The object is locked on a "begin transaction", several other calls are made with the lock in place, and then it's released with a "commit".'

Comment: Then MonitorEnter and MonitorExit should do the job for you.